# Judging a genetic algorithm's priority-based schedules by how far ahead the higher priority things are done

Tags: genetic-algorithms

I'm creating a schedule for a summer camp. Because of the high risk of rain, the higher priority activities need to be attempted first, so there is more time for later attempts if need be (temporarily ignoring the schedule in that situation).

Camp takes place over four days. My current idea is to map the days to a set of numbers (4, 3, 2, 1), and get a correlation between these numbers and the priorities of activities. But I'm not certain this is the best way to do it, nor what the best way of correlating the two are. I'm also not sure how I would factor this correlation in with the fitness function, along with the priorities themselves.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Can I ask why a simple sorting of activities by priority wouldn't suffice?